# Is there a way to return list of 10 rows of data at a time using a where condition from a database using native query?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, nativequery

I'm currently using a database where I'll be sending 10 unique Id's at a time and I'm expecting a list of objects in return.
Is there any way where I can use a native query to get this.

```
select * from tbl_bank_customer_accounts where uid in ('05b6864b-ad10-4efe-af8d-b556e02dfc75','19226ae6-72f3-40dc-a690-079c979a3044','1a196c99-007f-4edd-a8a1-556f070cc852' ,'1e88f4fb-101c-4f6c-acd0-100bd1d02237' ,'20511b9b-8e7b-44fb-ba79-5c2103679b39' ,'3564b980-59e3-411f-8cc2-1bffa3cf9883' ,'4491b692-b6a4-4581-b150-411ab03151a4' ,'6364b0eb-015c-422f-a5e2-ae00828c70d6' ,'6ed7a6a2-265d-4d59-8764-d7742296aa17' ,'93c99403-d099-401f-a544-44984dcfc925');
```

*the above one is my query can it be implemented using stored procedure*

Comment: select * from tbl_bank_customer_accounts where uid in ('05b6864b-ad10-4efe-af8d-b556e02dfc75','19226ae6-72f3-40dc-a690-079c979a3044','1a196c99-007f-4edd-a8a1-556f070cc852' ,'1e88f4fb-101c-4f6c-acd0-100bd1d02237' ,'20511b9b-8e7b-44fb-ba79-5c2103679b39' ,'3564b980-59e3-411f-8cc2-1bffa3cf9883' ,'4491b692-b6a4-4581-b150-411ab03151a4' ,'6364b0eb-015c-422f-a5e2-ae00828c70d6' ,'6ed7a6a2-265d-4d59-8764-d7742296aa17' ,'93c99403-d099-401f-a544-44984dcfc925');

Comment: the above one is my query can it be implemented using native query

Comment: I'd suggest to better put the SQL statement and your sub-question directly into your Question itself by Editing it

Comment: _Is there a way to return list of 10 rows of data at a time using a where condition from a database using native query?_ yes.  _can it be implemented using stored procedure_ Yes. It's not clear what you're actually asking here

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid my query is to get list of data from a db using the above condition by giving 10 or more data values in condition and getting the result in less time,

Comment: You've stated a third different requirement now. You want the result in less time

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid consider stored procedure and less time and can you suggest me a solution